# Tkinter optionmenu functions

Tags: python, function, tkinter, optionmenu

Using the Tkinter module, I am try to elicit an action based on the certain selection of an option menu and cancel that action if the option menu is not on the designated selection. The problem is that the program will compile except when both option menus = "treble clef" it somewhat stops working. I have tried using an if statement which works fine except I'm not sure how to get rid of the label it calls.

```
originalKey = Label(window, text = "Original Key Signature", bg = 'black', fg = 'white')
originalKey.pack()

oKey = StringVar(window)
oKey.set("Select") # initial value
optionold = OptionMenu(window, oKey, "treble clef", "bass clef", "alto clef")
optionold.config(bg = 'black', fg = 'white')
optionold.pack()

#new key selections option menu
def displayKey(str):
while nKey.get() == "treble clef" and oKey.get() == "treble clef":
    testpic = Label(window, image = logoimage, bg = 'black')
    testpic.pack()
    break

newKey = Label(window, text = "New Key Signature", bg = 'black', fg = 'white')
newKey.pack()

nKey = StringVar(window)
nKey.set("select") # initial value
optionnew = OptionMenu(window, nKey, "treble clef", "bass clef", "alto clef",             
command = displayKey)
optionnew.config(bg = 'black', fg = 'white')
optionnew.pack()
```

Comment: Are you aware you have an infinite loop that never exits? What are you hoping to accomplish by creating an infinite number of labels in a loop?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you please rephrase this so we know exactly what it is you are looking to achieve.